# Bootstrap sub-menu is wider than a parent-menu-item

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with Bootstrap menu - when a child is too long it's wider than the nav itself.

I've tried giving `<li>` elements a fixed width of 360px but it doesn't work - the text doesn't move to the second line.

Here's a live example:
If you click the first element in the sidebar you can see, that some child `<li>`s are too long and don't wrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to `white-space: initial;` your CSS..

```
nav.sidebar li a {
    color: #656565;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-left: 2px solid transparent;
    transition-duration: 200ms;
    white-space: initial;
}
```